# Php Sql group by date from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have three tables where I am trying to generate reports by joining all the tables. 
table opens:

```
id   |  offer_id   |  datetime
1    |  1          | 2017-08-19 00:00:00
2    |  1          | 2017-08-20 00:00:00
3    |  1          | 2017-08-20 00:00:00
```

table clicks:

```
id   |  offer_id   |  datetime
1    |  1          | 2017-08-20 00:00:00
2    |  1          | 2017-08-20 00:00:00
3    |  1          | 2017-08-20 00:00:00
```

table conversions:

```
id   |  offer_id   |  datetime
1    |  1          | 2017-08-20 00:00:00
2    |  1          | 2017-08-21 00:00:00
3    |  1          | 2017-08-21 00:00:00
```

I need to build a query where I can get the output like below

output required:

```
datetime                 |  opens      |  clicks  | conversions
2017-08-19 00:00:00      |  1          | 0        | 0
2017-08-20 00:00:00      |  2          | 3        | 1
2017-08-21 00:00:00      |  0          | 0        | 2
```

So far I have tried

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT opens.id) as opens,
count(DISTINCT clicks.id) as clicks,
count(DISTINCT conversions.id) as conversions
FROM opens

LEFT JOIN clicks
ON clicks.offer_id = 1

LEFT JOIN conversions
ON conversions.offer_id = 1

WHERE opens.offer_id = 1 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(opens.datetime, '%Y %M %D'), DATE_FORMAT(clicks.datetime, '%Y %M %D'), DATE_FORMAT(conversions.datetime, '%Y %M %D')
```

But this query is not giving me the desired output. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you the desired results it could be a complex SQL as below, first get list of dates from three tables using union then do a left join with your 3 tables on offer_id and date

```
SELECT groupdate,
COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS opens,
COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS clicks,
COUNT(DISTINCT con.id) AS conversions
FROM (
  SELECT offer_id,DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y %M %D') groupdate FROM opens 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT offer_id,DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y %M %D') groupdate FROM clicks
  UNION ALL
  SELECT offer_id,DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y %M %D') groupdate FROM conversions
) t
LEFT JOIN opens o ON (t.offer_id = o.offer_id AND t.groupdate = DATE_FORMAT(o.`datetime`, '%Y %M %D'))
LEFT JOIN clicks c ON (t.offer_id = c.offer_id AND t.groupdate = DATE_FORMAT(c.`datetime`, '%Y %M %D'))
LEFT JOIN conversions con ON (t.offer_id = con.offer_id AND t.groupdate = DATE_FORMAT(con.`datetime`, '%Y %M %D'))
WHERE t.offer_id = 1 
GROUP BY groupdate
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f25d6/11)

Comment: Hey, You are champ! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!